# show each column in the cross-tab in different background color -Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am Creating a `Cross-tab` with `Tableau Desktop 10.0.`

[image]

I need to show each column in the `cross-tab` in different `background color`. How to do this `tableau`. I have read about a method using `calculated columns`, but i am looking for other options. Also is it possible differentiate each columns with a line?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by calculated columns but the only way I know is to use a dummy Measure in the columns shelf and then place the actual measure you want on the Text pill. Set the marks to Bar and increase the size to full. Each Measure will have its own dummy Measure in the column shelf. Take a look at this example. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/160919%20stack%20question.twbx

As for differentiating each column with a line, you can do this by going Format > Borders > Column and adjust the Column Divider.

Comment: thanks for the answer bernardo.. I will have to  implement your solution in my workbook to see the changes. But regarding the borders, Column Divider draws border after officeid and budget spend. I need  separation between  each of the column fields ( actual hours, actual hours ly, budget spend). Please help